# Joint Waiting Times distribution in M/M/1 queue

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory

Consider an M/M/1 queue, where arrivals to the queue occur according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$. We assume FCFS (First Come First Serve) service discipline with i.i.d. exponential service times of rate $\mu$. For such a queue, we know that the stationary distribution of waiting times (queuing + service) of individual arrivals in the queue follow an exponential distribution of rate $\mu - \lambda$, i.e., the pdf of waiting time of $i^{th}$ arrival denoted by $W_i$ is given as
$$
f(W_i = w_i) = (\mu - \lambda) e^{-(\mu-\lambda) w_i}, w_i > 0.
$$

However, I am interested in finding the stationary distribution of two or multiple consecutive waiting times in the queue, i.e., $f(W_i, W_{i+1})$ or in specific $f(W_i, W_{i+1}, \ldots, W_{i+k})$ for some $k \geq 1$. Could someone guide me or refer me to some sources on how I can proceed with this.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use $W_{i+1}= X_{i+1}+\max\{W_i-V_{i+1},0\}$ for the service time $X_{i+1}$ and interarrival time $V_{i+1}$. This is useful if you condition on a known distribution for $W_i$.

Comment: Thank you @Michael